# A Question about Pareto Distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Below is a problem that I made up and my attempt to solve it. I am thinking I have the wrong answer and somebody here can tell me where I went wrong.
Thanks,
Bob

Problem:
The median net worth of a certain population is $100K$. To be in the top $10\%$ you need to have a net
worth of $1000K$. Assuming the population follows the Pareto distribution, what is the minimum net
worth you need to be in top $2\%$?
Answer:
Answer:
\newline
For the Pareto distribution we have:
\begin{eqnarray*}
 P(X > x) &=& \Big( \frac{x_m}{x}  \Big) ^ \alpha \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now we can setup two equations with two unknowns.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Big( \frac{x_m}{100}  \Big) ^ \alpha &=& 0.5 \\
\Big( \frac{x_m}{1000}  \Big) ^ \alpha &=& 0.1 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now we solve the two equations.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Big( \frac{x_m}{100}  \Big) ^ \alpha \Big( \frac{1}{10}  \Big) ^ \alpha &=& 0.9 \\
0.5 \Big( \frac{1}{10}  \Big) ^ \alpha &=& 0.1 \\
\Big( \frac{1}{10}  \Big) ^ \alpha &=& 0.2 \\
\alpha \ln{ 0.1 } &=& \ln{0.2} \\
\alpha  &=& 0.69897\\
\Big( \frac{x_m}{100}  \Big) ^ { 0.69897} &=& 0.5 \\
\Big( \frac{x_m}{100}  \Big) &=& 0.5 ^ { \frac{1}{ 0.69897 } } =   0.3709569 \\
x_m &=& 37.09569 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now we need to find the minimum net worth of the top $2\%$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Big( \frac{37.09569}{x}  \Big) ^ { 0.69897 } &=& 0.98 \\
\Big( \frac{37.09569}{x}  \Big) &=& 0.98 ^ { \frac{1}{0.69897} } =  0.9715102 \\
0.9715102 x &=& 37.09569 \\
x &=& 38.183531 \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you are using the tail (complement CDF) $P(X > x)$ already.

The second of your starting equations

> Now we can setup two equations with two unknowns. \begin{eqnarray*}
> \Big( \frac{x_m}{100}  \Big) ^ \alpha &=& 0.5 \\
> \Big( \frac{x_m}{1000}  \Big) ^ \alpha &=& \color{red}{0.9} \\
> \end{eqnarray*}

should be just directly the "top $10\%$"

$$ \Big( \frac{x_m}{1000}  \Big) ^ \alpha = 0.1$$

The solution is $x_m \approx 37.095689$ and $\alpha \approx 0.69897$. The left end cutoff $x_m$ is now a reasonably low value (hmm? totally a different universe from ours), and $\alpha > 0 $ gives the typical $1/x$ like shape.

The minimum of the top $2\%$ is exactly $10^4$K, and this is not a coincidence. By having the top $10\%$ to be ten times (in wealth) the top $50\%$, you are setting a power law that goes 10 times in wealth when you go one-fifth in top percentage. Thus $2\%$ is another 10 times of the $10\%$.

Comment: I updated my solution and now my $X_m$ and $\alpha$ matches yours. Also, your answer of $10^{4}K$ makes perfect sense. However, when I try to find it by using the distribution I get the wrong answer. Can you please tell me where I went wrong.  Thanks,  Bob

Comment: Two things: (1) if you're asking where your previous approach went wrong, then updating (correcting) the post in that way totally defeats the purpose of the question. (2) For the 2% calculation, you just made the same mistake yet again. It should be L.H.S. = 0.02 Actually when you see the 38 something, it's a confirmation that you're getting near the bottom ($x_m \approx 37$), the lowest 2% not the top.

Comment: I post here so that I can learn math. I was able to find the correct solution thanks to your help. If you would like, I will roll back my last edit to the question.

Comment: Don't worry about it this time. Just keep this in mind in the furture: readers who presumably will read your question first will find my answer very strange (unless I edit in response to your edit). I think somewhere in the Help Center there are a few sentences about avoiding "edits that invalidates existing answer posts."